# Overlay animation with multiple pictures

Tags: beamer, overlays, animations

I'm writing my thesis presentation on beamer. I need to write a frame which, in order

1. starts with some initial text and a picture
2. then adds more text
3. keep the same text, change the picture to a bigger picture and add an itemize list
4. add another element to the list

At the moment I have

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \onslide <1->
      text1\\
      \onslide <2->
     text2:
      \begin{itemize}
        \onslide <3-> \item item1
        \onslide <4-> \item item2
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}[H]
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
          \only <1,2> {small picture} %pictures are tikz picture on a separate file
          \only <3,4> {big picture}
        }
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problems with this code are that:

1. on slides 1 and 2 doesn't show the picture, only on slides 3 and 4
2. since the pictures have different size, the text on the side gets vertically shifted when switching to the big picture

edit: changed code

Comment: We can't compile your code. Please try to make an example for which we don't need additional files.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would avoid using unscoped `\onslide` if you build your frame non-linearly. You can control the appearance of elements much easier if you use `\only<>{...}` etc.
- to avoid shifts due to the changed image, you can use an `overlayarea` environment. Just make sure that the height of the environment (3cm in the example below) is tall enough to accommodate your tallest picture
- if you use `\uncover` you can avoid that new text will influence the page layout because the text is present on all overlays, just not visible at first
- beamer does not have a floating mechanism. It makes no sense to specify a floating specifier `[H]`. In fact, if your image does not have a caption, you don't really need a `figure` environment unless you want to centre your image.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \uncover<1->{text1\\}
      \uncover<2->{text2:}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<3-> item1
        \item<4-> item2
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}
          \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
            \only<1,2>{small picture} %pictures are tikz picture on a separate file
            \only<3,4>{big picture}
          }
        \end{overlayarea}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this works amazing, thank you! i had to change the height of the overlay area to match with my picture, but now is perfect